# Showing the existence of subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, hilbert-spaces

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space. Let $(x_n)_{n}\subseteq E$ and $(y_n)_{n}\subseteq E$ such that $\|x_n\|=\|y_n\|=1$.
Assume that $\forall\, \theta<1$, there exists $n_{\theta}$ such that $|\langle x_{n_{\theta}}\; ,\;y_{n_{\theta}}\rangle|> \theta$.

> How we can show the existence of  $(x_{n_k})_k$ and $(y_{n_k})_k$ two subsequences of $(x_n)_{n\geq1}$ and $(y_n)_{n\geq1}$ such that
>     $$\displaystyle\lim_{k\longrightarrow\infty}|\langle x_{n_k}\; ,\;y_{n_k}\rangle|=1.$$
>   How we construct $n_k$ such that $n_{k+1}>n_k$?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all $\theta_k=\frac{k}{k+1}<1$ there exists $m$ such that 
$$
|\langle x_{m},y_{m}\rangle|>\frac{k}{k+1}
$$
Set 
$$n_1=
\inf\left\{ m\in\mathbb{N}: |\langle x_{m},y_{m}\rangle|>\frac{1}{1+1}\right\}
$$
and 
$$n_{k+1}=
\inf\left\{ 
m\in\mathbb{N}:
m>n_{k} 
\mbox{ and }
|\langle x_{m},y_{m}\rangle|>\frac{(k+1)}{(k+1)+1}
\right\}
$$